# Selecting rows from a table depending on a column

Tags: sql-server, select

I have the following table (table1):

```
CODE    PRICE   ID
111     582     1
222     384     2
333     659     1
111     683     2
444     987     2
555     128     2
333     851     1
222     398     2
```

I need to group all codes and then show 3 columns, the code and then one with the sum of prices when ID = 1 and another one with the sum of prices when ID = 2.

The resulting table should be like this:

```
CODE    PRICE_1   PRICE_2
111     582       0
222     0         683
333     1510      782
444     0         987
555     0         128
```

I was able to create some querys, for example:

```
select CODE, (select SUM(PRICE) from TABLE1 where ID = 1), (select SUM(PRICE)
from TABLE1
group by CODE
```

but I get this, where PRICE_1 and PRICE_2 are the sum of all of them, not grouping them by CODE (111, 222, etc). I do not know how to group them inside the "sub-select".

```
CODE    PRICE_1   PRICE_2
111     2092      2580
222     2092      2580
333     2092      2580
444     2092      2580
555     2092      2580
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT CODE,
       (
           SELECT SUM(Price)
           FROM table1 a
           WHERE a.ID = 1
                AND a.CODE = b.CODE
       ),
       (
           SELECT SUM(Price)
           FROM table1 a
           WHERE a.ID = 2
                AND a.CODE = b.CODE
       )
FROM table1 b
GROUP BY CODE
```

Without re-read:

```
SELECT
    CODE,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN ID = 1 THEN Price END), 0),
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN ID = 2 THEN Price END), 0)
FROM table1
GROUP BY CODE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select code,case when id=1 then sum(price) end, case when id=2 then sum(price) end from R5ORDERLINES
```

group  by code,id order by  code

Try this it will work the Output will be

```
 Code  Price1  Price2
 111    582     NULL
 111    NULL    683
 222    NULL    782
 333    1510    NULL
 444    NULL    987
 555    NULL    128
```

there is a slight difference, but query is giving all the values.

Thanks